# What is the difference between serial and parallel algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I do heard about serial and parallel processing as well as programming. But my instructor asked the question what is serial and parallel algorithms. I search it on google but didn't find any easy and helpful content.

Would anyone please say something about it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm).

> Parallel algorithms are simply algorithms that allows parallel processing.

For example, take a look at [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), its normal recursive implementation is already a parallel algorithm (therefore merge sort is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)). Note that with n threads, the time complexity of merge sort will be O(log n) instead of O(n log n). Other examples include [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and a whole list that can be found [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Escandal/nesl/algorithms.html).

> Serial algorithms are algorithms that are not parallel algorithms (i.e. it doesn't allow parallel processing)

For example if you want to find maximum element of an array, you can do it as follow:

```
a = [2, 4, 3, 2]
ans = -Infinity
For i From 0 To Len(a) - 1
  ans = Max(ans, a[i])
Return ans
```

There is no way for the compiler/interpreter to run this as parallel because it is iterative. It's nature is to run sequentially. However, you can implement it differently to make it a parallel algorithm, for example:

```
Def Solve(arr)
  if Len(arr)=0
    Return -infinity
  if Len(arr)=1
    Return arr[0]
  Divide arr into two part left=arr[0..len(a)/2] and right=arr[len(a)/2+1..len(a)-1]
  Return Max(Solve(left), Solve(right))
a = [2, 4, 3, 2]
Return Solve(a)
```

With this implementation, `Solve(left)` and `Solve(right)` can be run simultaneously without any problem, so it is a parallel algorithm. Note that with n threads, the time complexity of this implementation will be O(log n) instead of O(n) in the previous example.

However, not every algorithm can be parallelized easily. In fact, there is a class of problem called [P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) which are very hard to parallelize efficiently. (e.g. [Circuit Value Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Value_Problem))